# How to debug application which can't launch on macOS 10.14.6

Tags: macos

## Issue

my application can't launch on macos 10.14.6,but macos 10.13 is well.
and when restart the macbook,it works well again.

laucher without any error dialog,just with dock icon jump and exit immediately.

the application use qt(5.9.3) framework.

## Log file

here is my console log:

```
默认  15:12:59.951356+0800    Dock    LAUNCHING:0x0-0x395395 HBuilderX foreground=1 bringForward=1 seed=3433 userActivityCount=0
默认  15:12:59.961034+0800    loginwindow -[PersistentAppsSupport applicationReady:] | App: HBuilderX, ready, updating active tracking timer
默认  15:12:59.961122+0800    loginwindow -[ApplicationManager checkInAppContext:eventData:] | ApplicationManager: Checked in app : HBuilderX
默认  15:13:00.029062+0800    runningboardd   Resolved pid 43872 to [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872]
默认  15:13:00.032215+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] This process will not be managed.
默认  15:13:00.032262+0800    runningboardd   Now tracking process: [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872]
默认  15:13:00.032893+0800    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting executable<HBuilderX(501)> from originator [daemon<com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd>:172] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor; foregroundApp:43872; ID: 363-172-5144; target: 43872> attributes = {
    <RBSDomainAttribute: 0x7fe44d404910; domain: com.apple.launchservicesd; name: RoleUserInteractiveNonFocal; sourceEnvironment: 0x0>;
}
默认  15:13:00.033090+0800    runningboardd   Assertion 363-172-5144 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>) will be created as active
默认  15:13:00.033895+0800    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting executable<HBuilderX(501)> from originator [daemon<com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd>:172] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor; foregroundApp:43872; ID: 363-172-5145; target: 43872> attributes = {
    <RBSDomainAttribute: 0x7fe44d409c60; domain: com.apple.launchservicesd; name: RoleUserInteractiveNonFocal; sourceEnvironment: 0x0>;
}
默认  15:13:00.033891+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
默认  15:13:00.034456+0800    runningboardd   Assertion 363-172-5145 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>) will be created as active
默认  15:13:00.034478+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Ignoring resume because this process is not lifecycle managed
默认  15:13:00.034683+0800    runningboardd   Finished acquiring assertion 363-172-5144 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>)
默认  15:13:00.034738+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Set darwin role to: UserInteractiveNonFocal
默认  15:13:00.034882+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
默认  15:13:00.035720+0800    runningboardd   Finished acquiring assertion 363-172-5145 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>)
默认  15:13:00.035733+0800    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 363-172-5144 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>) from originator 172
默认  15:13:00.039076+0800    Finder  Requested application <private> has policy 0, associated category:DH1009 associated sites:(null) equivalent bundle identifiers:io.dcloud.HBuilderX
默认  15:13:00.047086+0800    HBuilderX   FRONTLOGGING: version 1
默认  15:13:00.047116+0800    HBuilderX   Registering, pid=43872
默认  15:13:00.049420+0800    HBuilderX   CHECKIN: pid=43872
默认  15:13:00.074798+0800    launchservicesd CHECKIN:0x0-0x395395 43872 io.dcloud.HBuilderX
默认  15:13:00.075521+0800    HBuilderX   CHECKEDIN: pid=43872 asn=0x0-0x395395 foreground=1
默认  15:13:00.077609+0800    lockoutagent    Requesting policy for bundle IDs: (
    "io.dcloud.HBuilderX"
)
默认  15:13:00.077712+0800    loginwindow -[ApplicationManager checkInAppContext:eventData:] | ApplicationManager: Checked in app : HBuilderX
默认  15:13:00.079163+0800    lockoutagent    Requested application <private> has policy 0, associated category:DH1009 associated sites:(null) equivalent bundle identifiers:io.dcloud.HBuilderX
默认  15:13:00.079327+0800    HBuilderX   Registered, pid=43872 ASN=0x0,0x395395
默认  15:13:00.079529+0800    HBuilderX   Registered, pid=43872 cgConnectionID=a05af
默认  15:13:00.082901+0800    HBuilderX   BringForward: pid=43872 asn=0x0-0x395395 bringForward=1 foreground=1 uiElement=0 launchedByLS=1 modifiersCount=1 allDisabled=0
默认  15:13:00.083014+0800    HBuilderX   BringFrontModifier: pid=43872 asn=0x0-0x395395 Modifier 0 hideAfter=0 hideOthers=0 dontMakeFrontmost=0 mouseDown=0/0 seed=0/0
默认  15:13:00.083126+0800    HBuilderX   BringForward: pid=43872 asn=0x0-0x395395
默认  15:13:00.083178+0800    HBuilderX   SetFrontProcess: asn=0x0-0x395395 options=0
默认  15:13:00.084934+0800    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting executable<HBuilderX(501)> from originator [daemon<com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd>:172] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor; frontmost:43872; ID: 363-172-5146; target: 43872> attributes = {
    <RBSDomainAttribute: 0x7fe44d7132b0; domain: com.apple.launchservicesd; name: RoleUserInteractiveFocal; sourceEnvironment: 0x0>;
}
默认  15:13:00.085138+0800    runningboardd   Assertion 363-172-5146 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>) will be created as active
默认  15:13:00.087085+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
默认  15:13:00.087583+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Set darwin role to: UserInteractiveFocal
默认  15:13:00.087872+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
默认  15:13:00.088377+0800    runningboardd   Finished acquiring assertion 363-172-5146 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>)
默认  15:13:00.105026+0800    HBuilderX   Current system appearance, (HLTB: 1), (SLS: 0)
默认  15:13:00.111943+0800    HBuilderX   Post-registration system appearance: (HLTB: 1)
默认  15:13:00.159749+0800    distnoted   register name: com.apple.xctest.FakeForceTouchDevice object: io.dcloud.HBuilderX token: f428d pid: 43872
默认  15:13:00.192966+0800    distnoted   register name: com.apple.nsquiet_safe_quit_give_reason object: io.dcloud.HBuilderX token: f429e pid: 43872
默认  15:13:00.248519+0800    HBuilderX   NSApp cache appearance:
-NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance: 0
-appearance: (null)
-effectiveAppearance: <NSCompositeAppearance: 0x600001e7d200
 (
    "<NSAquaAppearance: 0x600001e7d280>",
    "<NSSystemAppearance: 0x600001e7d100>"
)>
默认  15:13:00.267405+0800    HBuilderX   Received configuration update from daemon (initial)
默认  15:13:00.336474+0800    runningboardd   [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872] Death sentinel fired!
默认  15:13:00.338689+0800    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 363-172-5146 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>) from originator 172
默认  15:13:00.348064+0800    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 363-172-5145 (target:executable<HBuilderX(501)>) from originator 172
默认  15:13:00.347110+0800    loginwindow -[PersistentAppsSupport applicationQuit:] | for app:HBuilderX, _appTrackingState = 2
默认  15:13:00.347146+0800    loginwindow -[PersistentAppsSupport applicationQuit:] | App: HBuilderX, quit, updating active tracking timer
默认  15:13:00.441246+0800    runningboardd   Removing process: [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872]
默认  15:13:00.455981+0800    runningboardd   Removing assertions for terminated process: [executable<HBuilderX(501)>:43872]
```

someone know why?
Thanks very much.

Comment: give more details please

Comment: So it is working since you rebooted?

Comment: @RichardBarber  yes.